# VBA: Load custom ribbion at runtime with access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ribbon

I try to load and display a ribbon out of a textfile in microsoft access via VBA at runtime.

So I call this code:

```
Dim strGUID As String
strGUID = "RadToolRibbons"

Const RadToolRibbonFile = "c:\Temp\Ribbons.xml"

Dim XMLText As String

With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
      XMLText = .OpenTextFile(RadToolRibbonFile, 1).ReadAll
End With

Application.LoadCustomUI strGUID, XMLText
```

But it does not show the ribbon. When I call the code again I get an error:

```
#32609 " this customization already loaded..."
```

The xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="true">
        <tabs>
            <tab id="tab1" label="MyNew">
                <group id="StartHelp" label="Help">
                    <button id="Test" label="Test" size="large" imageMso="AcceptTask" />
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>                                                                      
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

What Im doing wrong?

Comment: If it's already loaded, perhaps you should instead be using `.ActivateTab`. (Example [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/df7780a1-a92b-486f-ab60-f227f673152e/show-custom-ribbon-tab-at-workbook-open?forum=exceldev).)

Comment: I changed the second line of the xml to: "<customUI onLoad="RibbonOnLoad" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">" and added a sub: "Public Sub RibbonOnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)" to a module which calls: "ribRibbon.ActivateTab ("tab1")" but It seems this function is not called.

Comment: Do you get any ribbon UI errors?

Comment: I dont get any errors (the first time I call this)

Answer (score 1):

By default, if a VSTO Add-in attempts to manipulate the Microsoft Office user interface (UI) and fails, no error message is displayed. However, you can configure Microsoft Office applications to display messages for errors that relate to the UI. You can use these messages to help determine why a custom ribbon does not appear, or why a ribbon appears but no controls appear.

To show VSTO Add-in user interface errors

1. Start the application.
2. Click the File tab.
3. Click Options.
4. In the categories pane, click Advanced.
5. In the details pane, select Show VSTO Add-in user interface errors, and then click OK.

Read more about that in the [How to: Show Add-in user interface errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-show-add-in-user-interface-errors) article.

Comment: I activated the user interface errors but nothing changes. The first time everything seems to work fine but nothing is shown.

Comment: Try to use a newer XML namespace - `<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
` .

Comment: Same as before. No reaction. No error message but also no ribbon

Comment: If you get the `onLoad` callback you may call the `Invalidate` method to get ribbon refreshed.

Comment: I changed the second line of the xml to: "<customUI onLoad="RibbonOnLoad" xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">"; and added a sub: "Public Sub RibbonOnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)". But the sub is not called...